# Wiremock https connection refused

Tags: wiremock

```
@Rule
public WireMockServer wireMockServer = null;


public void setUp(File file) throws Exception {
    wireMockServer = new WireMockRule(options().dynamicPort().dynamicHttpsPort());
    wireMockServer.start();

    WireMock.configureFor("https","localhost", wireMockServer.httpsPort());
    WireMock.configureFor("localhost", wireMockServer.port());

}
```

> Error : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Resulting into connection refused. Can somebody help here

1. While mocking http -> it works fine
2. When mocking https -> it says Connection refused.

Comment: have you figure out?

Comment: dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58168813/tomakehurst-wiremock-tries-to-connect-to-8080-connection-refused - the interesting that I tries to connect to 8080 always.