# Tomakehurst Wiremock. Tries to connect to 8080. Connection refused

Tags: java, junit5, wiremock

```
@Test
    void resourceTo_Wired_ClientCall() {

        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().port(10021));
        wireMockServer.start();

            final MappingBuilder stubBuilder = get(urlMatching("http://demo1096495.mockable.io/client1"));

            stubFor(stubBuilder
                    .willReturn(aResponse()
                            .withStatus(200)
                            .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                            .withBody("{\"something\":\"test-wired\"}")));
            ;
```

Got error:

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
>   (Connection refused)

What is missed of any?

P.S. I use `WireMockServer` with `junit 5` and spring boot. with `junit 4` and `WireMockRule` all works well.

```
 testCompile "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.24.1"
```

Comment: Where do you get the error, in the actual test? You only posted the Wiremock setup. Why is the test trying to connect to :8080 if your port is 10021?

Comment: it happens on stubFor(..) the why is the question actually :) (with junit4 and WireMockRule config it works great though)

Comment: Side note : since you are using `stubFor` as static method - you configure the defualt wiremock instance which uses `8080` port by default. If you want to create stub for the instance, which you created  in the test, you should use `wireMockServer.stubFor` on the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/369

added:         `WireMock.configureFor("localhost", 10021);`

before  `wireMockServer.start();`

Then that error is gone. It passed to next lines.

P.S.
 Got some new thing..but that is different issue.